# how to solve rational problem solving question

Tags: probability, problem-solving

> Marissa can paint a garage door in $3$ hours. When Marissa works with Roger, they can paint the same door in $1$ hour. How long would it take Roger to paint the door on his own(answer to the nearest tenth)?

### My work

Marissa paints a garage door in $3$ hours

$\text{Marissa}+\text{Roger}=1$ hour

How long will it take roger$=x$

$x+3/x+1+x/x=$

It takes Roger $3.3$ hours.

Comment: I can't really understand your work. Could you explain how you get the equation $x+3/x+1+x/x$, and what it represents?

Comment: Some commonsense:  If $M$ and $R$ both take $3$ hours on their own, it would take them $1.5$ hours working together (since each can do half in $1.5$ hours).  So if $R$ takes longer than $3$ hours on his own, they will take longer than $1.5$ hours working together, so $3.3$ can not be right.

Comment: Regardless how you  established your equations, it is obvious that the answer must be smaller than 3 (Roger works faster).

Comment: is their a n equation that can represent that ? @lulu

Comment: To get an equation think how much work is being done in 1 hour by each. Marissa is doing $1/3$ of the work in 1 hour, and Roger is doing $1/x$ of the work in 1 hour. What should $1/3 + 1/x$ be?

Answer (score 1):

Marissa's *rate* is $\frac {1 door}{3 hours}= \frac 13\frac {door}{hr}$

Rogers *rate* is unknown.  Lets say it is $x \frac {door}{hr}$

Together their rate is $(\frac 13 + x) \frac {door}{hr}$ and that is $\frac {1 door}{1 hour} = 1\frac {door}{hour}$

So $(\frac 13 + x)\frac {door}{hr} = 1 \frac {door}{hr}$ so

$x = \frac 23\frac{door}{hr}$ and that is rogers rate; it can point $\frac 23$ of a door in an hour or $2$ doors in $3$ hours.

So what was the question again? .... Oh, you.... how long dooes it take Roger to pain a door.

So if that tirme is $t\ hours$ then  Roger paints $\frac 23 \frac {door}{hr}\times t\ hr = 1\ door$.

$\require {cancel}$

$\frac 23 \frac{door}{{hr}}\times t\ {hr} = 1\ door$

$t\ hr = 1\ door \cdot \frac 32 \frac {hr}{door} = 1\frac 12 hr$.

Roger can paint a door in $1 \frac 12$ hours